# Unable to fetch last created directory in cmd file using task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I am unable to fetch last created directory using .cmd file which is run through task scheduler. while running the same cmd file manually gives me the expected path.

Below is the code snippet used

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO (SET LastCreatedFolder=%%i)
```

Here `LastCreatedFolder` gets value when the script is run manually and it returns empty when run through Task Scheduler.

Comment: How would anyone know where your commend should operate.

Comment: The whole purpose of this line of code is to identify the last created folder and further fetch the latest log files from the folder for further analysis. This is executed on Windows platform. Does this answer your question?

Comment: You don't specify paths.

Answer (score 1):

When you run from Task Scheduler the working directory, `%CD%`, is not necessarily that which is current when you open or run the script in the usual manner. To ensure that it is, you should set it as needed at the outset.

The following example uses the directory holding the running batch file, `%~dp0`:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%~dp0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD-H/OD/T:C 2^>Nul') Do Set "Newest=%%A"
...
```

---

**Edit**

If changing the directory at the outset, interferes with other commands within your script you could alternatively include the directory within the `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD-H/OD/T:C "%~dp0" 2^>Nul') Do Set "Newest=%%A"
```